Is there a way to define field types for Parse Objects?
I am using Parse Server and Parse JS SDK to develop an application. I recently started using typescript for my project. The question is, Can I define field types for Parse Objects?
For example, I have defined a Parse object for a post, and I want it to have a title field of type string
const Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");

First of all I don't understand why the type of Post is any
Secondly, I want the following code to throw an error or warning:
const post = new Post();
post.set("title", 123) // title should be a string and not a number

How can I do this?
Thanks
I have searched parse github and the internet for hours and found nothing.
I have tried experimenting with the second and third argument of the extend function. But I couldn't figure it out. I don't know if it is related to what I am trying to do or not.

yes you can do it by defining a schema.
here is a sample code:
const myObjectSchema = new Parse.Schema('MyObject');

myObjectSchema.get();
myObjectSchema
  .addString('stringFieldName')
  .addNumber('numberFieldName')
  .addBoolean('booleanFieldName')
  .addDate('dateFieldName')
  .addFile('fileFieldName')
  .addGeoPoint('geoPointFieldName')
  .addPolygon('polygonFieldName')
  .addArray('arrayFieldName')
  .addObject('objectFieldName')
  .........

myObjectSchema.save().then((result) => {
  // returns save new schema
});

more details can be found in docs
https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#schema
